# PHP - Saving $row->fetch() to a variable results into bool(false)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am having problems with my fetch() query.
Since there seemed to be missing details, I'll try to log the complete run of my code here.

What i can do:

- Show all Users
- Show all Organizations

What i cant do:

- Give Users an Organization

**Structure of the User & Organization**

**User**

```
class User
{ 
    private $name;
    private $phone;
    private $email;
    private $designation; // Geschäftsführung, IT Leiter
    private $salutation; // Dr.
    private $userID;
    private $organizationID;

    private $Organization; // Class Organization

    public function __construct($user)
    {
        $this->name= $user['fullname'];
        $this->phone = $user['phone'];
        $this->email = $user['email'];
        $this->salutation = $user['salutation'];
        $this->designation = $user['userdesignation'];
        $this->userID = $user['userid'];
        $this->organizationID = $user['userorganizationid'];
    }
```

**Organization**

```
class Organization
{
    private $name;
    private $address;
    private $city;
    private $phone;
    private $organizationID;

    public function __construct($organization)
    {
        $this->name = $organization['organizationname'];
        $this->address = $organization['address'];
        $this->city = $organization['city'];
        $this->phone = $organization['phone'];
        $this->organizationID = $organization['userorganizationid'];
    }
```

I start everything by calling /quickticket/user/userorganization.
This opens my routing:

```
Route::get('/quickticket/user/userorganization',
[UserController::class, 'indexUserOrganization'])->name('showUserOrganizations');
```

Now my indexUserOrganization method is called here:

```
public function indexUserOrganization() // Shows all Users with their Organization informations in a side
{
   $Users = UserController::getUsers();
   foreach($Users as $User)
   {
        $Organization = UserController::getOrganizationByUser($User);
        UserController::setOrganizationByUser($User, $Organization);
   }

   return view('QuickTicket/User/userorganization')->with('Users', $Users);
}
```

getUsers() is the following method:

```
public function getUsers() // Get all Users without their Organization
{
    try {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=myhost.de;dbname=mydbname;charset=utf8', 'user', 'XYZ');
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "There was an error connecting to the database";
    }

    $sql = "SELECT `swusers`.`fullname`, `swusers`.`userdesignation`, `swusers`.`phone`, `swusers`.`userorganizationid`,
    `swusers`.`salutation`, `swuseremails`.`email`, `swusers`.`userid`
    FROM `swusers`
    INNER JOIN `swuseremails`
    ON `swuseremails`.`linktypeid` = `swusers`.`userid`
    ORDER BY UPPER(`fullname`)";
    $row = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $row->execute();
    $users = $row->fetchAll();

    $i = 0;
    foreach($users AS $user)
    {
        $Users[$i] = new User($user);
        $i++;
    }

    return $Users;
}
```

Up to this point everything works wonderfully, I can display the users as well as the organizations separately(Index for User || Organization only).

Now `$Organization = UserController::getOrganizationByUser($User)` is the next called method.

```
public function getOrganizationByUser($User) // Get from the User the Organization as object
{
    $organizationID = $User->getOrganizationID();
    $Organization = OrganizationController::getOrganizationByUserOrganizationID($organizationID);

    return $Organization;
}
```

Followed by `OrganizationController::getOrganizationByUserOrganizationID($organizationID)`
the DB Connection is the same as in my UserController.

```
public static function getOrganizationByUserOrganizationID($organizationID) 
{
    $pdo = OrganizationController::DBConnection();

    $sql = "SELECT `organizationname`, `address`, `city`, `phone`, `userorganizationid`
    FROM `swuserorganizations`
    WHERE `userorganizationid` = :organizationID";


    $row = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $row->bindParam(':organizationID' , $organizationID);
    $row->execute();
    //var_dump($row->fetch());
    $organization = $row->fetch();
    //var_dump($organization);
    $Organization = OrganizationController::ArraytoClass($organization);



    return $Organization;
}
```

**(var_dumps are ALL commented out!)**

The method $Organization = OrganizationController::ArraytoClass($organization) looks like this:

```
public static function ArraytoClass($organization)
{
    $Organization = new Organization($organization);


    return $Organization;
}
```

Now when the constructor is called in the ArraytoClass method, it gives the error message:

**ErrorException
Trying to access array offset on value of type bool**

```
(\app\Classes\QuickTicket\Organization.php:16)
(Line 16 = $this->name = $organization['organizationname'];)
```

Now I tried to find out where the problem occurs.
Therefore I have used var_dumps once `$row->fetch()`, as well as once on `$organization`

Should I do it at `$row->fetch()`, it will show me my array with the correct data there, without `bool(false)`

However, if I now comment out the var_dump for `fetch()` and use it for `$organizations`, it returns me a `bool(false)` there.

I am only looking for 5 attributes, which are returned to me correctly (In this example, the organizationID = 20 and a SQL command directly in PHPMyAdmin works as desired)

```
var_dump($organization) = array(10) { ["organizationname"]=> string(8) "XXXXXXXX" [0]=> string(8) "XXXXXXXX" ["address"]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" ["city"]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(0) "" ["phone"]=> string(11) "01234567891" [3]=> string(11) "01234567891" ["userorganizationid"]=> int(20) [4]=> int(20) } bool(false)
```

I am still a beginner and don't understand how this happens.
fetchAll() would work, but would then have to access it in the constructor of Organization e.g. like this: `$this->name = $organization[0]['organizationname'];`

I hope this is more clear now.

Note* No active var_dump(), only to see why this happens with the examples!

Comment: `$row->fetch()` advances the cursor to the next result set and returns it (or `false` if there are no more results).

Comment: @EmanuelVintilă Hello,  if i var_dump my fetch() it gives me my data back without a bool(false). But as you can see in my examples, i get all my desired data back. Or what am i understanding wrong?

Comment: Please, for the love of what is holy, just **remove every single var_dump** from your code. This is all you need

Comment: @YourCommonSense Already did, i also told in my Note, that i still get the errors without var_dump. The only reasons they are there is, because i had this issue before. (Also both commented as seen in my code)

Comment: WHICH errors? What EXACT error message do you get?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Trying to access array offset on value of type bool

Comment: WHERE does it say? On which line?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Line 16, Organization

This is my public function __construct($organization)
Line 16: $this->name = $organization['organizationname']

Comment: then you need to remove the extra fetch() as well. given the code you posted before, the problem is clearly double fetch. and you failed to remove the extra one from your actual code. the current version works. Just make your actual code the same. You have to understand that your problems are not related to PDO, PHP or programming. There is no technical solution.there is no code-related fix. Thre is nothing to fix. The code you posted here is correct. You just need to make your code consistent. Also you need to make sure that the code, when you run it, actually returns the requested data

Comment: What is the value of $organizationID when you get that as a parameter?

Comment: @LajosArpad I open a route which opens indexUserOrganization() which opens getUsers() which returns all Users as Objects. Afterwards i use getOrganizationByUser($User), which gets the organizationID, and calls afterwards the getOrganiationByUserOrganizationID($organizationID) to now give the Users their Organizations.

The only fetch() between the whole code is a fetchAll() while i call the method getUsers()

Value of $organizationID is the UserOrganization in my User. If this may help: I have no issues to show all Users, or all Organizations. Only if i try to give a User a Organization

Comment: Again: what's the value of $organizationID?

Comment: Can you show the exact code you have? I do not have any contextual information about your project, I only know what you have described in the question. Referring to anything else is referring to the unkown from my (and other answerers') point of view.

Comment: Your question does not contain a call to getUsers(). Which line do you get the error at?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I must say that I am somewhat pleased with the answer. Because if my code is correct and still does not work, now just the error must be found. Everything was already commented out at the beginning, if it should work, it probably has other reasons. Have also updated my post now with every class and code that is running. Maybe it will be clearer then.

Comment: Do you have PHP error reporting turned on? Such an error could happen if you are accessing a non-existent variable. What happens if you try to access a deliberately non-existent variable? Does your code report it?

Answer (score -1):

The [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) says that `$fetch_style`, which is the first parameter of `fetch()` defaults to PDO::FETCH_BOTH, which is:

> PDO::FETCH_BOTH (default): returns an array indexed by both column
> name and 0-indexed column number as returned in your result set

so, we get a collection of column name/index - column value pairs, which obviously represents a record. This means that the [iterator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern) is in use here. So, if you call `fetch` for the first time, then the first record is fetched. If you call `fetch` for the second time, then, since the first record was already fetched when you called `fetch` for the first time, you fetch the second record and so on. The fact that you have fetched and then var_dumped `fetch` again, returning a `false` value means that your query is correctly executed and a single record is returned. So, try this:

```
$organization = $row->fetch();
var_dump($organization);
```

The reason as of why this works is that `fetch` is called only once, in order to get the first record and reuse the result, instead of calling it twice.

Even though in this specific case you are not going to have to iterate the results, because you have a single record in the results, this is how you can use the iterator pattern to your advantage:

```
while ($record = $row->fetch()) {
    //do something with $record
}
```

Comment: I don't get what does the fetch style to do with the rest of the answer and with the iterator pattern in particular. To me, this answer is even more confusing than the question

Comment: not to mention that the question is a crystal clear off topic, the problem is caused by the output from a leftover var_dump()

Comment: If i dont use any var_dump, it gives me an error that i have a array on type bool.
So i´ve used these 2 var_dumps to specify my issue.

If i use the first var_dump, i get my array back without a bool(false)
If i use (only) the second var_dump, direcly after $organization = $row->fetch()
i will see a bool(false)

My issue here is, that even without var_dumps, my array will have a bool(false)

Comment: @YourCommonSense Hi, could you say me how a commented var_dump will affect my code? I´ve heared this now a few times, but i dont have any var_dump not commented as my error appears (Array on type bool), these var_dumps where only there, as i have seen, that var_dump($row->fetch()) gives me the right result without bool, and as soon as i put it into $organization i will see the bool.

Comment: @YourCommonSense fetch style has to do with the fact that the asker calls `fetch`. One will not understand what `fetch` does in their case unless they know what their parameters (none in this case) do. In our case the fact that column key/value pairs are returned shows that a record is returned. Which shows that it is the iterator pattern, applying a stack-like behaviour. So, if you fetch something, then it's no longer there. This is what the asker needs to understand.

Comment: @DanielH you are fetching records from your collection multiple times. var_dump($yourresponse->fetch()) will retrieve the record there. Subsequent calls will not do it. $yourresponse->fetch();$yourresponse->fetch(); will fetch the record the first time and provide you a boolean the second time. The `->fetch()` in your code should happen *exactly* once. I know that var_dump "only" shows some result, but if you ->fetch() a record inside of that, then you will not be able to get the same record via a subsequent call to ->fetch().

Comment: @LajosArpad Question, if i remove all my var_dumps(), does my code normly should work? This is my issue i have all the time. Everyone tells me to remove my var_dumps, while they are normly all commented out. I dont have any var_dump active, while the error appeared first. I only used them to see where the issue appears.

Or does i still dont understand what you want to say to me?

Comment: @DanielH your code should work if and only if 1) your parameter to the function is correct 2) your database credentials are correct 3) your query executes correctly and 4) you do not use fetch() multiple times. To know what your exact error is I would need to know what your exact code is at this point and some other information, like the value of $organizationID you receive as a parameter.

Comment: @LajosArpad Well, after all these answers i guess i have to edit my whole thread again. I will edit this the next hour/s with all methods that i call till i get to this issue. (organizationID = 20 in this case, SQL query runs in SQL like i want it to do)

Comment: @DanielH if you run the query directly pasted into the db cli (replacing the parameter with the value of 20), does it run successfully?

Comment: @LajosArpad Yes it does, I have adjusted the post, hope that now everything is inside what is needed.

Comment: @DanielH thank you for your effort. So, at the line of ```$Organization = OrganizationController::ArraytoClass($organization);``` you pass a boolean instead of a record. That means that ```$organization = $row->fetch();``` returned false. Which is either a missing row or an error. I know you have tried this a dozen of times, but still. If you comment out the fetch line and uncomment the var_dump, is it showing proper values? It would be strange. Also, van you var_dump($organizationID)? Maybe it's a different value or a different type than expected. It's worth double-checking these.

Comment: @LajosArpad If i get it right:
ArraytoClass gets a bool, so my Object cant be created.
So the issue is before.
My data is always correct (with 5 attributes easy to track), i dont have issues to show all Organizations(without their Users)


var_dump($row->fetch()) (No $organization=fetch afterwards) = Undefined variable: organization (No $organization = undefined vatiable)

Data is correct, no bool(false)

var_dump($organization) after $organization = $row->fetch() shows the correct data, with bool(false)

I used the SQL Statement with the 20, and got the correct tuple.

Comment: @DanielH yes, the issue is before. My current understanding of your problem is that if you replace the fetch line with a var_dump, then the var_dump shows accurate values. This is quite a strange behaviour.

Comment: @LajosArpad I thought the same. I also have a ArraytoClasses() method, which runs through the constructor (Foreach to show all Organization).

That works just fine. I had issues to run my code, if i dont use static functions. I just used them,  but i dont know if the issue maybe appears there.

As far as i know, a overloaded constructor is not possible, but i could solve this issue semi with a bool given to my constructor.

Another question if you dont mind, does my code looks okay? Im new to OOP and dont know if this are too much methods im calling to attach a organization.

Comment: @DanielH I'm sure there is an easy solution to your problem. The thing is that there are many pitfalls and since, as you have stated, you do not have much experience, you surely have fallen into one. I tried to detect which it is with the questions, but it seems that I am not finding the question that needs to be asked. Your code is more-or-less okay, naturally, there are things to tweak, but let's worry about smaller issues when this one is fixed. If we could discuss this in chat, then there would be a higher chance of finding what the issue is.

Comment: And if we know what the issue is, then the solution will be simple. At least I think so.